# JQPlot pie chart throwing "Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot

I'm using the JQuery based charting library jqPlot (and the pie chart plugin from it) to generate a very basic pie chart.  It works fine in FF, etc. but (surprise!) not in IE.  In IE it actually loads okay and looks fine, but once I roll my mouse over the chart it throws the following error:

> Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined

The way I'm setting everything is very straightforward:

```
var optionsObj = {
               seriesColors: ['#3399cc', '#cc6666', '#7ba550', '#ffcc66', '#d17314'],
               grid: {
               },
               seriesDefaults: {
                  renderer: $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                  rendererOptions: { lineLabels: true, lineLabelsLineColor: '#777'}
               }
               };

            line1 = [['Coffee', 9],['Beer', 4],['TV', 6],['Lost umbrellas', 2],['Bicycle rides', 10]];
            chart = $.jqplot('pieDiv', [line1], optionsObj);
```

I should also mention that I'm using the modified pie chart plugin that includes label lines, but I get this problem even when using the regular pie chart plugin.  This can be found here: http://blog.statscollector.com/line-labels-for-the-pie-chart-in-jqplot/

Has anyone who has used this library before come across something like this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: tried your example , didn't get any error on IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var optionsObj = {
               seriesColors: ['#3399cc', '#cc6666', '#7ba550'],
               grid: {
               },
               seriesDefaults: {
                  renderer: $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                  rendererOptions: { lineLabels: true, lineLabelsLineColor: '#777'}
               }
               };

            line1 = [['Coffee', 9],['Beer', 4],['TV', 6],['Lost umbrellas', 2],['Bicycle rides', 10]];
            chart = $.jqplot('pieDiv', line1, optionsObj);
```

Comment: I edited the original post to reflect your comment.  I actually modified the code in hopes of making it simpler and missed that I accidentally left out the one set of brackets.  So that was a good eye, but not related to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing series colors.Yo have 3 series colors while line 1 has 5 groups.